# C# change property after object is build with constructor

Tags: c#

Hey ill have to do some user management stuff and after i created a new user i want to change his name but it doesnt change. what do i do wrong??

```
    private static bool TestNameSet()
    {
        bool ok = true;
        try
        {
            User user = new User("Abc", "def", "efg");

            user.Name = "hhhh";

            ok &= user.Name == "hhhh";
            ok &= user.FirstName == "def";
            ok &= user.Email == "efg";                

            Console.WriteLine("User set name: " + (ok ? "PASSED" : "FAILED"));
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User set name: FAILED");

            Console.WriteLine("Error: ");
            Console.Write(exc.Message);
        }

        return ok;
    }
```

with this i want to test if the name has changed

```
public sealed class User
{
    public string _name, _firstname, _email;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {

            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_name == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }                                
        }
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        //similar to name
    }
    public string Email
    {
       //similar to name
    }    


    public User(string name, string firstname, string email)
    {
        if (firstname == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        else if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        else if (email == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        _firstname = firstname;
        Name=_name = name;
        Email=_email = email;            

    }     
}
```

would be great if you guys could tell me what is wrong with my code im new to this so dont be too harsh ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting `_name` in the setter and you are testing the backing field for `null`, not the value passed in. Modify:

```
set
{
    if (_name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }                                
}
```

to:

```
set
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    _name = value;                                
}
```

and all will be well.